# Problems running Sencha Touch / PhoneGap example code on android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

Hi guys I'm running through this tutorial:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap

and trying to get the code running on Android. I'm set up with Eclipse and targeting Android 2.3.3

I've downloaded the final code from Git but I keep getting the error (in LogCat):

02-01 14:59:08.709: E/Web Console(16659): Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/app/app.js:8

The code in question is:

```
Ext.regApplication({
    name: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        this.launched = true;
        this.mainLaunch();
    },
    mainLaunch: function() {
        if (!device || !this.launched) {return;}
        this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();
    }
});
```

I get the same error whether running on the emulator or a physical device. I've got Weinre set up but it didn't give me any useful information, only stating 
"error occured: [unknown filename]:[unknown lineno]: [unknown message]"

Comment: Is there any reason you're blocking the Viewport launch waiting for phonegap to load?

Comment: The viewport contains code that relies on the PhoneGap APIs being available so it's blocked until PhoneGap is loaded.

Comment: You could always defer calling Ext.regApplication until phonegap loads. This would avoid the weird launch logic required here. It might be a little slower, but I question how *much* slower, especially if you're already including sencha-all. It could be less than 10ms.

I played around with JS concatenation for a while, and I was only able to save <10ms after combining 20 JS files, so I wonder how much performance optimizations like this matter.

Comment: Thanks Stefan do you have any sample code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>` to AndroidManifest.xml and it should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that "app" is conflicting with the App class in PhoneGap which is accessible at navigator.app. Try changing the name to "myapp" and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response Simon. I made this change and unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Comment: How odd, well I've just re-read the tutorial and it appears that at line 8 of app.js that you should have already have received the deviceready event from PhoneGap so navigator.device should exist. Do you have an event listener for deviceready?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue but it only occurs when including the JS file for weinre to work.  If you remove that on my setup it loads the application fine.  Not sure why and currently on the hunt to get it fixed as need weinre to help with debugging of course!